# Can I display a pdf in webview instead of downloading it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

I'm using webview to display a website in an android app. On the site I want to display are pdf files located. My question is if i can display the .pdf files directly in the app instead of just downloading the file. The code below is for downloading the file.

```
myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

                DownloadManager.Request myRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                myRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                myRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

                DownloadManager myManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                myManager.enqueue(myRequest);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "variable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

I tried something like:

```
myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

                DownloadManager.Request myRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                myRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                myRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

                myWebView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });
```

I think there is a way to put the url as a variable in the code, but I don't know how I can make that work.

Comment: A WebView cannot display a pdf document.

Comment: It is possible. There are a few examples on youtube but they only show how to only display a pdf.

Comment: You are wrong informed. And if you dont provide links or examples..

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4_JSLy1fsc&t=531s&ab_channel=DevNami for example

Comment: That does not load a pdf document in a webview. Google gives a html document for it.

Comment: That works for me. Is there a way to implement that in the code above?

Comment: Then you should change the subject of your post and write a different post.